# S3 - blocks any CORS request, no matter what

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, cors

Okay, so I have an S3 bucket that's totally public, with the loosest CORS config I can think of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration>
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

...and I still get the classic `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`.

I've followed every other StackOverflow thread/tutorial/etc I can find. I'm not using CloudFront or any other CDN, and it's just a basic AJAX request for a PDF.

Is... there something I'm missing? I'm out of ideas here.

Comment: I think it's your browser that is causing this.
try using `jsonp` method or the adding option `xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }` in the ajax.

Comment: @new_user — Adding `withCredentials: true` will trigger a preflight OPTIONS request which is more likely to **cause** this problem than prevent it.

Comment: @new_user — JSONP is a dirty hack that we used before CORS was available.

Answer (score 1):

Eugh. Okay, it turns out Chrome just gives up on any CORS request from localhost. I suppose I'll just use Firefox for this project.

Cheers new_user and Quentin for your help!